# Handling a jQuery.when.apply with unexpected number of arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger multiple requests, preserving the order and ignoring the errors. As a first timer javascript programmer, after scouting the docs and code around, the following pattern emerged:

```
var requests = [];
for (yadda yadda) {
    request.push($.ajax())
}
$.when.apply(null, requests).always(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var result = arguments[i];
        // do things 
    }    
})
```

It is my understanding that when called in that way creates a master deferred that triggers only when all deferreds in requests are done (either successfully or not).

Unfortunately, the above code does not work in the case requests contains only one element. When that happens, the `when` behaves in a different way, and my always() callback does not receive an array of length one, but instead the single response object, unpacked.

I see solutions for this problem, but none that is idiomatic (or an alternative approach that is).

Comment: @A.Wolff because I don't know how many arguments that callback is going to receive... it depends on the number of requests

Answer (score 0):

It's a workaround, but why not use the `length` of `results` to determine your expected response? Then you would always have an expected `array` you can work with.

```
if( requests.length == 1 ) {
    arguments = [arguments];
}
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/m7sLe1ph/1/)**

Another solution would be to change the structure and use it in correct jQuery pattern. Then you will always receive the responses as `array` and got no further touble.

```
$.when(requests).always(function(response) {
    response.forEach(r => console.log(r));
})
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/m7sLe1ph/4/)**

And note that you got an typo in your example. It should be `requests`, not `request`.

```
requests.push($.ajax());
```

Comment: So you are saying there's no more elegant way to handle this use case?

Comment: Not in your syntax. I've extended my answer for a *nicer* solution. @StefanoBorini

Comment: wouldn't the second option always return only one element (the first) as the argument response?

Comment: No, why do you think this? It works fine and returns result by result. Take a look at the console and play with it. ;) @StefanoBorini

Comment: Because according to jquery documentation, if you pass something that is not a deferred, it will fire immediately with the passed object (in this case an array). That solution makes me think that you will probably get the array, but its internal deferreds may not be completed.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Now I'm not sure anymore. Have to investigate on this. But the first solution will work. @StefanoBorini